# Swing applications with EJB

Tags: java, swing, ejb

Any one tell, is it better to use EJB for datahandling(1.functions- like calculations ,2.database handling  and when database remote & local) in swing applications and

what about the performance/speed of running comparing to normal swing applications  with java classes (@ running 1. middle size 2. large size applications)?

Does using EJB with swing sense that we make simple thing a big thing,complex unnecessarily?

(Let's say ejb may run in JBOSS container.I know if ejb is used, it can be used in web applications as well. )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really need a centralized application with the server where every fat client can connect to, I wouldn't do calculations on the server side, one of the most important aspects when deciding to use fat client's (swing apps) is to move the workload associated with the calculations on the client, database handling on the other hand would be done on the server side, otherwise there is no point, I guess, to keep the central server at all. At the end of the day it really depends what are you trying to achieve, you can read more about fat/thin clients pros and cons [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.115864.15)

Comment: I mentioned "calculations" for just refer some functions. You are right, normal calculations are better to be handled in client side. Any way, thank you very much for your information and your link. :)